# form.submit() skips validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

The required attributes like textbox,checkbox is not validated when there is following code inside onclick event in submit button:

```
onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true;"
```

It seems "this.form.submit()" bypasses the validation for required attribute. If I remove onclick it works.

Comment: When you call the `submit` method programatically the events will not be triggered

Comment: How is your submit added, is it a jQuery one, if so `$(this.form).submit();`

Comment: Form submit action has the higher priority than the click action, better try

    ` form.submit(function(){ $("#mybutton").click(function(){ //your code }) })`